# Regex/Textmate Confusion

Tags: regex, textmate, oniguruma

I'm trying to create a Textmate snippet, but have run into some difficulties.  Basically, I want to type in a Name and split it into its parts.

Example,

Bill Gates: (Bill), (bill), (Gates), (gates), (Bill Gates), (Bill gates), (bill Gates), (bill gates)

EDIT**

So I most certainly can produce these results quite simply if I was using a programming language.  For example, I could split the words and then call the uppercase or lowercase functions to produce this output.

But in my situation I am using Textmate and it regular expression capabilities to create a tab snippet.  I want to type some trigger key, ie doit, press tab and then type in a username.  Then the ouput above will be created.  This won't save me that much time, but I feel like I come across this sort of stuff in Textmate quite frequently and want to figure it out.

I have been using this as a reference, but still don't know how use regexps to be selective with the words and upper and lowercase the values (\u \U \l \L)

http://manual.macromates.com/en/snippets

Comment: Indeed, I am confused as well... I don't see the relation between "split it" and your example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [use Ruby for textmate snippets](http://drnicwilliams.com/2008/06/11/using-ruby-within-textmate-snippets-and-commands/). That should make it simpler.